# I can not add dependencies for a Maven project in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

[Generate (alt + insert)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gw7QJ.png)
[Generate -> add depency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbN0G.png)

I've noticed that on some computer on windows, when you create a maven project on intellij, you can't generate dependencies in the pom.xml file.
So when I do alt + insert in the pom.xml file at dependencies level, I don't get the "dependency" option but just "add dependency".
However, when I do "add depency" and then press "add" after finding my dependency, the addition doesn't work, nothing autogenerates in the "dependencies".
I tried deleting intellij entirely and reinstalling because I thought maybe I had an obsolete version but it didn't work even after reinstalling.

Comment: You do not *generate* (that word doesn't even have any sense in this context) dependency. By default, new Maven project won't have any dependencies (what you expect it to have?).. and you should add whatever dependency you wish, as a `<dependency> ... </dependency>` element. Read more [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html).

Comment: I think I misspoke, sir.
To add a dependency, normally when I press alt+insert which is then "Generate", I don't get the dependency option displayed. This option is supposed to help me search for the dependency that I want to add to my pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Please disable "Package Search" plugin in "Settings | Plugins". Currently there is an issue with buttons (Add, Update, etc.): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PKGS-1341